# Loading part of a dataset using load() method from Tensorflow datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to load the [quick draw dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/quickdraw_bitmap) from Tensorflow datasets to Google Colab. But since its too large(~30GB) I want to download or load only a part of it. Can I do this using load() method in tensorflow_datasets?

This is the code:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

    dataset, metadata = tfds.load(name="quickdraw_bitmap", with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, please read [TFDS: Splits and slicing](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/splits).

```
dataset, metadata = tfds.load(name="quickdraw_bitmap", 
                              with_info=True, 
                              as_supervised=True,
                              split='train[:10%]')
```

Comment: Does this mean it would only download 10% or load 10 from the complete package? Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure. And thanks, don't hesitate to vote on the question if it helped you.